# Sorry! question regarding moving within safety zone

Tags: sorry

Scenario:
Red has two pawns in home and two in the safety (pawn-a on 5, pawn-b on 2). Red draws a 3.

Question:
Must red move pawn-a up to pawn-b, thus killing pawn-b, or is Red allowed to forfeit this turn?

Rule 6: Moving Pieces
Once pieces have been entered they are moved forward in the direction of the arrows on the board, unless otherwise directed by the cards.  Pieces may pass each other, whether or not they are of the same color.  The occupied square counts like any other.  Pieces of the same color may not occupy the same space.  If a player is unable to make a move, for this or any other reason, he forfeits his turn.  However, a player MUST make any move directed by the cards drawn if possible, whether or not this is to his advantage.  A player may move 1 piece (or divide his move among 2 pieces if he draws a "7"), or enter a piece at each turn as the cards allow.  When a move ends on a square occupied by an opponent the latter is sent back to his START.

Comment: What part of the rules you quoted doesn't answer your question? It's pretty clear to me from this excerpt of your quote: *"**Pieces of the same color may not occupy the same space. If a player is unable to make a move, for this** or any other **reason, he forfeits his turn**."* There's also no mechanism to send your own pawn back to the start: *"When a move ends on a square occupied by **an opponent** the latter is sent back to his START."* (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 6):

Red's turn would be forfeited according the the rules on hasbro.com since they have no legal moves.

[Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Sorry.PDF)

> Two pawns of the same color may never occupy the same space. If your only possible move would make you land on a space already occupied by another of your own pawns, you forfeit your turn.

Comment: Hmm...I've always interpreted it as:
Two pieces may not share a space, whether or not they are of the same color.
If your piece is able to move, you must.  If there is a pawn in the final square, that pawn goes back to START, whether or not it is of your own color...similar to the slide rule that if you end on the triangle and slide, all pawns along the slide return to START, even your own.

Comment: @Guest Not sure what that is supposed to mean as the rules I linked are not numbered.

Comment: Could be a difference in rules between editions.  I'm direct quoting from my game box.

Comment: @Guest It could be a difference but I am giving a direct quote from the rules on the hasbro site which one would assume are the most current and up to date version of them.

Comment: Damn it, now the hard part...do I tell my wife I was wrong?  We played last night and the game ended abruptly because of my misinterpretation.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A person CAN forfeit their turn if the only place they could move to (no sliding) would force their own pawn back to START.

Comment: Please provide a transcript of whatever text is in that image.